# const std::vector<const CSensor *> as this argument discards qualifiers

Tags: c++

I can't understand why i can see still that comunication from compilator , i have used const vector and also my  pointer which i declared it's also a const , some sugestions ?

base.cpp

```
 void CBase::setSensor(const CSensor *pSensor) const 
 {

   if(table.size() < size_of_table) 
   {
    table.push_back(pSensor) ;
   }
   else
      throw CException("Przekroczono rozmiar tablicy , pozostale sensory nie zostaly dodane");

  }
```

base.h

```
  vector <const CSensor *> table;
```

I tried to use diffrent combination of  const but still nothing.

Comment: The `const` after `void CBase::setSensor(const CSensor *pSensor)` means `this` is a pointer-to-const, and you can't modify any data members in the function. It is probably an error to make a setter a `const` function.

Comment: so , how can i solve that problem . I have to add this pointers to my vector

Comment: if `table` is a non-mutable member of `CBase`, you cannot modify (`push-back`) it in a const method

Comment: thank you guys for explanation , i got it . I have just removed at the end of setSensor  :)

Comment: Unrelated: Don't do `using ...` in the global namespace in your header files.

Comment: Ja. Some poor fool will include the header and suddenly have bugs in their code. They'll waste hours debugging and ultimately find your header. What happens next depends a lot on just how much stress the other programmer is under and just how prone to violence they are.